# How do you update only the year in and keep day and month - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column that contain date and for each row i would like to update only the year for example :

```
-------------
date
-------------
22/01/2013
16/02/2013
19/08/2013
23/01/2013
```

i want to change for every row only the year  part like this :

```
-------------
date
-------------
22/01/2012
16/02/2012
19/08/2012
23/01/2012
```

change it for the whole table
thanks

Comment: What do you expect for 2012-02-29 (feb 29 in iso format)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using:

```
Update TableName set date = DateAdd(yy,-1,Date)
```

should subtract one year from each date field for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Update table_name set date_field=DateAdd(yyyy,2012-year(date_field),date_field)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DATEADD

```
UPDATE my_table
SET [date] = DATEADD(year,-1,[date])
```

http://sqltutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2007/06/sql-dateadd-function.html